# How to delete mass records using Map/reduce script?

Tags: mapreduce, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, saved-searches

I have created a Map/Reduce script which will fetch customer invoices and delete it. If I am creating saved search in UI based on the below criteria, it shows 4 million records. Now, if I run the script, execution stops before completing the "getInputData" stage as maximum storage limit of this stage is 200Mb. So, I want to fetch first 4000 records out of 4 million and execute it and schedule the script for every 15 mins. Here is the code of first stage (getInputData) -

```
            var count=0;
                var counter=0;
                var result=[];
                var testSearch = search.create({
                    type: 'customrecord1',
                    filters: [ 'custrecord_date_created', 'notonorafter', 'sta​rtO​fLa​stM​ont​h' ],
                    columns: [ 'internalid' ]
                }); 
                do{
                    var resultSearch = testSearch.run().getRange({
                        start : count,
                        end   : count+1000
                    });
                    for(var arr=0;arr<resultSearch.length;arr++){
                        result.push(resultSearch[arr]);
                    }
                    counter = count+counter;                        
                }while(resultSearch.length >= 1000 && counter != 4000);
                return result;
```

During creating the saved search, it is taking long time, is there any work around where we can filter first 4000 records during saved search creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not a custom mass update?

It would be a 5-10 line script that grabs the internal id and record type of the current record in the criteria of the mass update then deletes the record.

Comment: Yes, that might work. But I was trying to test whether we can do it in Map/reduce.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what [`search.runPaged()`](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/49291/kw/search.runpaged) and [`pagedData.fetch()`](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/49305) is for.

`search.runPaged` runs the current search and returns summary information about paginated results - it does not give you the result set or save the search.

`pagedData.fetch` retrieves the data within the specified page range.

Answer (score 0):

If you are intent on the Map/Reduce you can just return your created search. Netsuite will run it and pass each line to the next phase. You can even use a saved search where you limit the number of lines and then in your summarize phase re-trigger the script if there's anything left to do.

The 4k record syntax though is:

```
var toDelete = [];
search.run().each(function(r){
    toDelete.push(r.id); 
    return toDelete.length < 4000;
});
return toDelete;
```

finally I normally do this as scheduled mass update. It will tend to interfere less with any production scheduled and map/reduce scripts.

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType MassUpdateScript
 */
define(["N/log", "N/record"], function (log, record) {
    function each(params) {
        try {
            record.delete({
                type: params.type,
                id: params.id
            });
            log.audit({ title: 'deleted ' + params.type + ' ' + params.id, details: '' });
        }
        catch (e) {
            log.error({ title: 'deleting: ' + params.type + ' ' + params.id, details: (e.message || e.toString()) + (e.getStackTrace ? (' \n \n' + e.getStackTrace().join(' \n')) : '') });
        }
    }
    return {
        each:each
    };
});
```

Comment: Yes, In Map/reduce that's what i have done, to get 4k records. But issue is first it will create saved search returning 4 million records. That will take lot of time. Once saved search is created it will return first 4k records to next stage. I am looking for filtering the result during search creation, anything in search.filter

Comment: If you just create and return the search object. Don’t run the search.