# I can't do mass delete on netsuite

Tags: netsuite, crm

I have 20K records trying to delete from NetSuite but the search result is only returning 50 records per page so the max I can delete is 50 - any support on that

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51304600/how-to-delete-mass-records-using-map-reduce-script/51312001#51312001

Answer (score 3):

You can change the number of records returned per page in your preferences.  Go to Home > Set Preferences and in the General tab look for Optimizing NetSuite.  In that section you should see a setting for Number of Rows in List Segments.  You can set this to 500 to allow you to delete 500 at a time.

Another approach would be to create a mass delete script - a quick search will come up with several examples of this. This would require a bit more initial effort, but will pay off in the long term if you have a regular need for it.

Answer (score 2):

A common method to delete a lot of records is to execute a mass update script like below which deletes the records passed in.

```
function deleteRecords(rec_type, rec_id) {
    try { nlapiDeleteRecord(rec_type, rec_id); } 
    catch (err) { log('error','Error deleting '+rec_type+' id '+rec_id); }
}
```

A mass update script is basically a search that runs the script for each record returned. You do get a chance to see the search results before executing the script. Search the NetSuite help for Mass Updates and Mass Update Scripts.

Comment: Thanks, Brian - will make sure to test the script, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use a map reduce that has an input param thats a txt field. Copy/paste list of IDs to delete